# Converting http response without nested map()

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable

I think I am missing something here, since I find using Angular http.get with pipe(map) from RXJS quite counter intuitive:

The backend returns an array of simple objects (see **Unifiedparams** interface below). I want to extract an `Observable<String[]>` and pass it on to the **app.component.html**, where I use `*ngFor="let param of params$ | async"` to build a dropdown.

I can't seem to be able to access the **name** attribute without nested maps although the returned json is a single dimension array.

```js
fetchParams(): Observable<String[]>{
    const result = this.http.get<unifiedParam[]>('http://localhost:5000/getparams');
    const params:Observable<String[]> = result.pipe(map(unifiedParams => res.map(unifiedParam=>unifiedParam.name)));
    return params;
}
```

This seems to indicate that the Observable is an array itself but using `this.http.get<unifiedParam>` and `rows:Observable<String>` respectively results in **rows** being empty:

```js
fetchParams(): Observable<String>{
    const result = this.http.get<unifiedParam>('http://localhost:5000/getparams');
    const params:Observable<String> = result.pipe(map(unifiedParam=> unifiedParam.name)));
    params.pipe(tap(console.log)); //doesn't print anything
    return params;   
}
```

So my question here is if using `Observable<UnifiedParam[]>` and `.pipe(map(res=>map(el=>el.name)` is the way to go.

Thanks!

Update: Forgot the interface  :)

interface unifiedParam {
    name: String,
    source: String
};

Update 2: To clarify what puzzles me: 
Why do I need the outer map() function.
Isn't map() defined for arrays?

Comment: Where is the interface for Unifiedparams?

Comment: @robert1 sorry forgot to add it

Comment: answer updated to explain a little more why 2 map functions and differences. Hope it helps.

Comment: `params.pipe(tap(console.log));` not working because you are not subscribing to it, you have to change it like: `return params.pipe(tap(console.log))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure to understand your question/need.

If your backend api returns an array of `UnifiedParam` model, so `UnifiedParam[]`, and you need to retrieve an array of names, so `string[]`, and if your model looks like :

```
UnifiedParam {
  ...
  name: string
  ...
}
```

so your first approach is fine.

Just a little refactoring of your code:

```
fetchParams(): Observable<String[]> {
  return this.http.get<UnifiedParam[]>('http://localhost:5000/getparams').pipe(
    map(unifiedParams => unifiedParams.map(unifiedParam => unifiedParam.name)) 
  )
}
```

My advice is also to correctly type your models, and also use comprehensive variable/argument names. (for instance, inside `map` operator : `unifiedParams`...).

It will help to keep code clear and maintainable.

**Updated**

In your code, there are 2 `map` functions :

- one is an array map function, to iterate on each item of an array, and transform it by returning a "projection" of it, or any other new object.
- second one, is an `Observable` operator, which means: for every value emitted in the stream, transform it to another value.

So here, in other words:

- invoke an Get Http request to retrieve a list of `UnifiedParam`.
- when server reply, receive a stream (Observable) with only one value (array of `UnifiedParam`) and then this stream will complete itself.
- for each value in the stream (so the only one), we transform it (the array of UnifiedParam) to a new array of names.

Hope it's more clear with this update.

Comment: Thx @Thierry Falvo for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your `array` to an `Observable` and flatmap it, then use only one map operator (from `Observable` this time) :

```js
fetchParams(): Observable<String> {
  return this.http.get<UnifiedParam[]>('http://localhost:5000/getparams')
             .pipe(
                 mergeMap(unifiedParams => from(unifiedParams)),
                 map(unifiedParam => unifiedParam.name) 
              )
}
```

Notice that you'll not receive an `Observable<String[]>` but directly `Observable<String>`, i don't know if this suits you

Comment: This is interesting, however "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."
Also fromArray seems to be obsolete, its "from" now.